# Why won't upcast to concrete type of another common interface

Tags: c#, interface, casting, upcasting

Why can't you upcast to a different concrete type of another common interface. I've created this example in linqpad.  Now I can understand if you had different properties between the two classes that an up cast would fail because it couldn't complete the object.  But in this Scenario I don't see why the upcast would fail.

```
void Main()
{
    ICommon test = new ConcreteA();

    ((ConcreteA)test).a.Dump();

    // this errors with: Unable to cast object of type 'ConcreteA' to type 'ConcreteB'.
    ((ConcreteB)test).a.Dump();
}

public interface ICommon
{
   string a {get; }
}

public class ConcreteA : ICommon
{
    public string a {
        get{ return "Concrete A"; }
    }
}

public class ConcreteB : ICommon
{
    public string a {
        get{ return "Concrete B"; }
    }
}
```

Shouldn't the compiler be able to treat this as if you were casting from an double to an int,  if a double was too big for an int it would throw an exception but if the cast was possible the compiler would do it.  Why doesn't the compiler try to load the ConcreteA as a ConcreteB and if there were extra properties in the ConcreteB that it couldn't figure out then it would throw.

Comment: Why are you trying to cast in that scenario anyways? Just use `a.Dump`.

Comment: That's just not a C# feature. If you want to be able to cast between two different custom classes, you need to define your own conversion operator.

Comment: Suppose ConcreteB has another property "x" (not defined in `ICommon`) and compiler allowed that cast. What would happen when you call `((ConcreteB)test).x`

Comment: @Eser I would expect it to throw a run time error in that case.

Comment: Why Am I getting down voted for this? This is a valid question with valid form why must trolls hate?

Comment: "Could it be that my question isn't perfect? No, no, it's the trolls!"

Comment: I know it's not perfect but I didn't think it sucked so much to be down vote

Comment: Not that I downvoted. But seriously, two downvotes is no big deal. And you have 2 upvotes now!

Comment: woot I broke even thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `ConcreteA` knows nothing about `ConcreteB` (in your case, because they may have different implementation for property `a`), I suggest you implement explicit operator for ConcreteB like this:

```
public class ConcreteA
{
    /* rest of your code ... */

    public static explicit operator ConcreteB(ConcreteA instance)
    {
        // implement converting from ConcreteA to ConcreteB
    }
}
```

For more info about explicit operator: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xhbhezf4.aspx

Comment: Is there an attribute for this in which it automatically attempts to cast on the properties that have the same name

Comment: @johnny5 if you want to map properties between two classes, [Automapper](http://automapper.org/) is your friend :)

Comment: I have automapper, I didn't want to do that either I just wanted it to be built into C#.  I was looking for the most lazy solution possible

Comment: @johnny5 The laziest solution would be to use `dynamic` for all of your types.  Of course then you're throwing out all the performance, safety, and maintainability that C#'s type system provides.  At that point you may as well be working in Python.

Comment: Note that this won't resolve the error that is encountered in the OP since the source of the cast is a local of interface type. User-defined casts are not looked up at run time (unless the expression is dynamic), they must be resolved at compile time.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are trying to cast to a different class that has nothing to do with the first one other that it supports the same interface. What you are trying to do is some sort of Duck typing which is not supported in C#.

In your case you want to call the method directly on the interface without the cast like:

`test.a.Dump()`

That's the reason in the first place why you would use the interface. It is a contract of a class "what capabilities it supports".

Comment: I guess I wasted C# to be more dynamic in the sense that since it inherited from the same interface it would try to case to the opposing type if I requested it to,

Comment: I don't understand that logic.. The point of the interface is that you don't have to care what the concrete type is!

Comment: @Blorgbeard Yeah I was just trying to do this because I was using the interface to later to be serialized, but I didn't want to implement ISerializeable

Comment: Well the Serializers that come with .net  can already serialize everything simple and some complex stuff out of the box pretty well. I would look into serialization in the MSDN or here on stacko to see if there is help in that direction to make it easy. IIRC there are attributes where you can instruct the serializer to certain behavior,